# NoSuchMethodError instead of calling correct method

Tags: java, overriding, nosuchmethoderror

I came across a weird behavior. The following code:

```
private void setSegments(Set<Long> segments) {
    this.segments = ImmutableSet.copyOf(segments);
}
```

throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
```

I checked the class contents via reflection by adding following snipped into the method:

```
try {
    Class c = ImmutableSet.class;
    Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        LOGGER.error("method: " + m[i].toString());
    }
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Which, among all other methods, printed out

```
Segments:method: public static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(java.util.Iterator)
Segments:method: public static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(java.lang.Iterable)
```

I do not understand why the method with Iterable parameter isnt called. After all, Set extends Collection which implements Iterable.

thanks for any ideas

Comment: Can you show how you invoke the method, or what implementation of `Set` you pass there? I have just checked it by passing `HashSet` and I get no error.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Guava?

Comment: You are compiling with a different version of whatever Google JAR you are using than what you are executing with. Or else you are executing without the Google JAR in the CLASSPATH at all.

Comment: @michalk
HashSet is passed to the method.

Comment: @Overflow404 according to build.gradle it should be: compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '24.0-jre' unless its somehow magically overwritten by any other libraries with guava dependencies

Comment: @user207421 i am compiling with gradle jar and running a jar file

Comment: I checked it with `27.1-jre` version and got no error while passing `HashSet`.